# document.body is null when adding react component to meteor project

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am trying to add a react component to a meteor project. It works well when I run it in the browser but when I run on ios emulator or device, I will get an error.

template:

```
<template name="navbar_datepicker">
  <div>
    {{> React component=DesktopInfiniteCalendar}}
  </div>
</template>
```

component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InfiniteCalendar from 'react-infinite-calendar';
import 'react-infinite-calendar/styles.css';

var today = new Date();
var minDate = Number(new Date()) - (24*60*60*1000) * 7; // One week before today

export default class DesktopInfiniteCalendar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<InfiniteCalendar width={400} height={600} selectedDate={today} minDate={minDate} keyboardSupport={true} rowHeight={40} />);
  }
}
```

helpers:

```
import DesktopInfiniteCalendar from './datepicker_components.js';

Template.navbar_datepicker.helpers({
  DesktopInfiniteCalendar() {
    return DesktopInfiniteCalendar;
  }
});
```

The above code works in combination with the meteor package [react-template-helper](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-with-blaze), but in the browser only.

The error I get on emulator and real device is:

```
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.appendChild')
    exports (modules.js:43659)
    (anonymous function) (modules.js:1645)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    require (modules-runtime.js:109)
    (anonymous function) (modules.js:809)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    require (modules-runtime.js:109)
    import (modules.js:394)
    (anonymous function) (app.js:2657:539)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    require (modules-runtime.js:109)
    global code (app.js:13231)
```

Any thoughts about why this happens?

Comment: It's possible that it's executing the order in such a way that the JS on the page executes prior to the Document.body being there.  I am not sure how you determine if this is the case, or how to "fix" it, but that's the only reason I could think of that would cause document.body to be null.  For instance, with jQuery you would typically wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` to make sure your jQuery code doesn't trigger to soon.

Comment: Why mix React with Blaze?, just asking.

Comment: Simplicity mainly, I am using just one react component in the app for now and meteor has an excellent guide showing me how to be able to do that.

Comment: @CodeChimp It was a load order issue and using `$(document).ready()` helped. I think your comment would do as a correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Vijay There are some things that you really can't do in plain React, at least not easily.  For instance, the recommended approach to using the accounts packages still wraps the Blaze implementation with a React component.  They may have changed that w/ the 1.4 release, but I know even the tutorials had to do it that way.